# Python plot legend is not draggable. gives an error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have data and I am trying for produce the plot. It does produce plot but legend is not draggable. It gives me an error mentioned below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import ast
...................
...................
.
.
.
.
.   

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in datafile:
    plt.plot(f[0],f[1])




plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)
plt.legend(datanames)
plt.legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)
plt.legend().draggable()    


plt.grid()  
plt.show()
```

I am trying plot and it gives me an error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draggable'

How can it be fixed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `plt.legend` it creates a *new* legend (discarding the old).  None of you artists have a label, so no legend gets created and `plt.legend` returns `None`.  Just do it like so:

```
legend = plt.legend(datanames, loc='best', numpoints=1)
legend.draggable()
```